# Cakephp 3.0.x: helpers for errors

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In my error layout (`src/Template/Layout/error.ctp`) I'm trying to use a custom helper, but I see that CakePHP loads automatically only the `Html` and `Form` helpers.

How to load other/custom helpers in case of error?

Thanks.

Comment: It is a bad idea to depend on anything for rendering errors, are you usre your custom helper isn't the reason for your problem? Alternatively, [create your own error controller](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#creating-a-custom-controller-to-handle-exceptions).

Comment: @ AD7six you are right, it's a bad idea. Forget it.